# How to bold only the clicked item and unbold any other item at the same time in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a navigation header that makes that navigation item the only bold item when clicked and all other items normal text. I would also like to create new components for each navigation item clicked, but for now I just want to be able to make the item I'm clicking on bold.

I am very new to react so please bear with me, and I am using functional react because it makes more sense to me so far than classes.

So far it works to click on each header navigation item and set it to bold, and click again and set it to normal text. What I need to understand is how to set only the item clicked to bold and the rest back to normal text.

As mentioned, I'm brand new to react and would prefer to understand this using functions, not classes. Because the majority of information out there is for classes, I've found it difficult to translate the available help from classes to functions, thus my question.

I have this for App.js:

```
import Header from './components/Header'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I have this for Header.js:

```
const Header = () => {
    return (
        <header>
            <nav className="level has-background-white-ter">
                <div className="level-left">
                    <figure className="media-left">
                        <p className="image is-64x64"><img src="logo.png" alt="something"/></p>
                    </figure>
                    <div className="level-item">
                        <strong className="title">Header</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="level-right">
                    <>
                        <Nav />
                    </>
                    <p className="level-item"><button className="button"><a href='/logout'>Logout</a></button>&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    )
}

let headerItems = ['Page-1', 'Page-2', 'Page-3', 'Page-4', 'Page-5', 'Page-6', 'Page-7', '[Page-0]']
const Nav = () => {
    const changePage = (e) => {
        e.target.style.fontWeight =
        e.target.style.fontWeight === "bold" ? "" : "bold";
        console.log(e)
    }
    return (
        headerItems.map((value, index) => {
            return <p className="level-item" name="nav" key={index} id="summary" onClick={changePage.bind(this)}>{value}</p>
        })
    )
}

export default Header
```

I am using Bulma for CSS, so I have this for index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>Hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I believe I need to manage property state for each item somehow. Any and all guidance in how to do this with functional react is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I'm correct you want to bold the font weight if item was clicked for now. Have you tried to achieve it with CSS? if so, would you share the code?

Comment: @yahyaparvar it is already bolding the item when clicked, and unbolding the item when clicked again. The problem is that I want only that item to be bolded, and the rest unbolded. What's happening is any item clicked gets bolded/unbolded.

Comment: I would remove the `functional-programming` tag. Your question is about React functional components, but it's not about functional programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is you're not updating the styles of previous active link and for that You can use state hook to store the active index of the nav and than use that index to update the style using style Prop or using classes. In the below code, I used the style prop to update the font weight based on active index.

`import { useState } from "react";` // import hook

Than declare the state using above hook.

`const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);` // I've initialized with null, you can store the initial index as well in the state. You can learn more about hooks in the [official guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Than you can update your changePage function to get and update the index of the clicked item.

```
const changePage = (e, index) => {
console.log({ e });
setActiveIndex(index);
// e.target.style.fontWeight =
//   e.target.style.fontWeight === "bold" ? "" : "bold";
// console.log(e);
  };
```

After that, you can use the index state to update the styling (font weight in your case).

```
return headerItems.map((value, index) => {
return (
  <p
    className="level-item"
    name="nav"
    key={index}
    id="summary"
    style={{ fontWeight: activeIndex === index ? 600 : 400 }} // conditional styling.
    onClick={(e) => changePage(e, index)}
  >
    {value}
  </p>
);
  });
```

Below is the complete Header.js file.

```
    import { useState } from "react";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav className="level has-background-white-ter">
        <div className="level-left">
          <figure className="media-left">
            <p className="image is-64x64">
              <img src="logo.png" alt="something" />
            </p>
          </figure>
          <div className="level-item">
            <strong className="title">Header</strong>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="level-right">
          <>
            <Nav />
          </>
          <p className="level-item">
            <button className="button">
              <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
            </button>
            &nbsp;
          </p>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

let headerItems = [
  "Page-1",
  "Page-2",
  "Page-3",
  "Page-4",
  "Page-5",
  "Page-6",
  "Page-7",
  "[Page-0]"
];
const Nav = () => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);
  const changePage = (e, index) => {
    console.log({ e });
    setActiveIndex(index);
    // e.target.style.fontWeight =
    //   e.target.style.fontWeight === "bold" ? "" : "bold";
    // console.log(e);
  };
  return headerItems.map((value, index) => {
    return (
      <p
        className="level-item"
        name="nav"
        key={index}
        id="summary"
        style={{ fontWeight: activeIndex === index ? 600 : 400 }}
        onClick={(e) => changePage(e, index)}
      >
        {value}
      </p>
    );
  });
};

export default Header;
```

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-state-demo-kebdz) link of your example.

Comment: Thank you! This answer is excellent direction for me.. I was struggling to understand how to use setState, and this perfectly describes it.